# Modo de compatibilidade Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, debug

Uso wordpress e preciso fazer esse código funcionar. Upei ele e to usando o debuger do firefox pra saber onde estão os erros. Já substitui todas `$` por `jQuery`, mas na linha 18 ele ta dizendo que `jQueryrainbow.slider` não é uma função. Detalhe esse código é funcional foi feito pelo CODEPEN.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.fn.pickify = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            jQuerypicker = jQuery(this);
            jQueryic0n = jQuerypicker.children('.ic0n');
            jQueryinput = jQuerypicker.children('input.change');
            jQueryboard = jQuerypicker.children('.board');
            jQuerychoice = jQueryboard.children();
            jQueryrainbow = jQuerypicker.children('.rainbow');

            var colors = jQuerypicker.attr('data-hsv').split(',');
            jQuerypicker.data('hsv', {h: colors[0], s: colors[1], v: colors[2]})
        var hex = '#'+rgb2hex(hsv2rgb({h: colors[0], s: colors[1], v: colors[2]}));
        jQueryinput.val(hex);
        jQuery('body').add(jQueryic0n).css('background-color', hex);

            // making things happen
            jQueryrainbow.slider({
          value: colors[0],
          min: 0,
          max: 360,
                slide: function(event, ui) {changeHue(ui.value)},
                stop: function() {changeColour(jQuerypicker.data('hsv'), true)}
        })
            jQuerychoice.draggable({
                containment: '.board',
                cursor: 'crosshair',
                create: function() {jQuerychoice.css({'left': colors[1]*1.8, 'top': 180-colors[2]*1.8});},
                drag: function(event, ui) {changeSatVal(ui.position.left, ui.position.top)},
                stop: function() {changeColour(jQuerypicker.data('hsv'), true)}
            });
            jQueryboard.on('click', function(e) {
                var left = e.pageX-jQueryboard.offset().left;
                var top = e.pageY-jQueryboard.offset().top;
                jQuerychoice.css({'left': left, 'top': top});
                changeSatVal(left, top);
                changeColour(jQuerypicker.data('hsv'), true);
            });

            // drag var actions
            function changeHue(hue) {
                jQueryboard.css('background-color', 'hsl('+hue+',100%,50%)');
                var hsv = jQuerypicker.data('hsv');
                hsv.h = hue;
                changeColour(hsv);
            }
            function changeSatVal(sat,val) {
                sat = Math.floor(sat/1.8);
                val = Math.floor(100-val/1.8);
                var hsv = jQuerypicker.data('hsv');
                hsv.s = sat;
                hsv.v = val;
                changeColour(hsv);
            }

            // changing the colours
            function changeColour(hsv, restyle, hex) {
                var rgb = hsv2rgb(hsv);
                if (!hex) {var hex = rgb2hex(rgb)}
                jQuerypicker.data('hsv', hsv).data('hex', hex).data('rgb', rgb);
                jQueryic0n.css('background-color', '#'+hex);
                jQueryinput.val('#'+hex);
                if (restyle) {
                    changeStyle(rgb);
                }
            }
            function changeStyle(rgb) {
                var rgb = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';
                jQuery('body').css('background-color', rgb);
            }

            // input change
            jQueryinput.keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.which != (37||39)) {
                    inputChange(jQueryinput.val());
            }
            });
            function inputChange(val) {
                var hex = val.replace(/[^A-F0-9]/ig, '');
          if (hex.length > 6) {
            hex = hex.slice(0,6);
          }
                jQueryinput.val('#' + hex);
                if (hex.length == 6) {
                    inputColour(hex);
                }
            }
            function inputColour(hex) {
                var hsv = hex2hsv(hex);
                jQueryic0n.css('background-color', '#'+hex);
                jQuerychoice.css({
                    left: hsv.s*1.8,
                    top: 180-hsv.v*1.8
                });
                jQueryrainbow.children().css('left', hsv.h/3.6+'%');
                jQueryboard.css('background-color', 'hsl('+hue+',100%,50%)');
                changeColour(hsv, true, hex);
            }


            function hex2hsv(hex) {
                var r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2),16)/255;
                var g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4),16)/255;
                var b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6),16)/255;
                var max = Math.max.apply(Math, [r,g,b]);
                var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [r,g,b]);
                var chr = max-min;
                hue = 0;
                val = max;
                sat = 0;
                if (val > 0) {
            sat = chr/val;
            if (sat > 0) {
              if (r == max) {
                            hue = 60*(((g-min)-(b-min))/chr);
                if (hue < 0) {hue += 360;}
              } else if (g == max) { 
                hue = 120+60*(((b-min)-(r-min))/chr); 
              } else if (b == max) { 
                hue = 250+60*(((r-min)-(g-min))/chr); 
              }
            } 
                }
                return {h: hue, s: Math.round(sat*100), v: Math.round(val*100)}
            }
            function hsv2rgb(hsv) {
                h = hsv.h;
                s = hsv.s;
                v = hsv.v;
                var r, g, b;
                var i;
                var f, p, q, t;
                h = Math.max(0, Math.min(360, h));
                s = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, s));
                v = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, v));
                s /= 100;
                v /= 100;
                if(s == 0) {
                    r = g = b = v;
                    return {r: Math.round(r*255), g: Math.round(g*255), b: Math.round(b*255)};
                }
                h /= 60;
                i = Math.floor(h);
                f = h - i; // factorial part of h
                p = v * (1 - s);
                q = v * (1 - s * f);
                t = v * (1 - s * (1 - f));
                switch(i) {
                    case 0: r = v; g = t; b = p; break;
                    case 1: r = q; g = v; b = p; break; 
                    case 2: r = p; g = v; b = t; break; 
                    case 3: r = p; g = q; b = v; break; 
                    case 4: r = t; g = p; b = v; break; 
                    default: r = v; g = p; b = q;
                    }
                return {r: Math.round(r*255), g: Math.round(g*255), b: Math.round(b*255)};
            }
            function rgb2hex(rgb) {
          function hex(x) {
              return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
          }
          return hex(rgb.r) + hex(rgb.g) + hex(rgb.b);
            }
        });
    };

    jQuery('.picker').pickify();

});
```

Comment: Como você inclui esse código na sua página?